# Can I use Thread.Sleep when the loading spinner and the error message has the same element xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the logic I am trying to implement. I press a tab in a page and if there is an error message, I System.out.println a custom error message to the console. If the error message does not occur, I proceed with other functionalities.

The problem is after I click the tab, there is a spinner that loads before loading the data. Xpath for the spinner and error message is the same. So, When the WebDriver sees the spinner, it identifies it as an error and gives me an error message.

When I add a Thread.Sleep in between, then it identifies the loaded section and is not giving me the error message.

Apart from using Thread.sleep, can I do anything to wait until the data loads properly after the spinner?

```
    private Boolean BenInErr() throws InterruptedException
{
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        WebDriverWait BErr = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
        WebElement BErrText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='plan-details-benefits-and-cost-content']/div/services-list/div/mc-loading-error/div/div/span"));
        //String Text = BErrText.getText();
        BErr.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(BErrText));
        return BErrText.isDisplayed();
    }

    catch (Exception Ex1)
    {
        System.out.println("Benefit information is available");
        return false;
    }
}

public void mngBenInfErr() throws InterruptedException
{
 if (BenInErr())
{
    System.out.println("There is an error in Benefits & Coverage tab in Benefit information section");
}
}
```

Comment: If the problem revolves around the error message and spinner being identified via the same XPath expression, then have you considered using expressions that match only one or the other?  This should be possible without changing the document in which the expressions are resolved, but it might be done more easily if you're open to changing the document to better distinguish the target elements from each other.

Comment: I see you're using the ExpectedConditions class. In C# we have `ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement` - if that is something available to you in Java, it seems like a good thing to wrap your WebDriverWait around.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I got a hint from Arman's comment and used the below code to take out the Thread.sleep.   
 return Text.equalsIgnoreCase("Error loading benefit information."); Thanks.

Comment: Don't `catch (Exception Ex1)`, catch specific checked exceptions. You don't handle `Thread.sleep` correctly - you don't explicitly catch `InterruptedException` and you don't re-interrupt the thread when you do. You also should follow the naming conventions. `mngBenInfErr` and `BErr` violate the conventions.

Comment: Both methods are declared `throws InterruptedException` but neither one does. Neither one should, either.

Comment: Please post the HTML around the error and the spinner. You should be able to easily find a way to distinguish between them.

Comment: Thanks, all. I resolved this one. I will catch the specific exceptions later. This is a pilot run. I can't understand //You don't handle Thread.sleep correctly - you don't explicitly catch InterruptedException and you don't re-interrupt the thread when you do. You also should follow the naming conventions.// Can you give a link to a resource from which I can get to know what you are saying @LewBloch ? I will rename the methods. Thanks.

Comment: Read _Java Concurrency in Practice_, by Brian Goetz, _et al._ If you're looking for something online, surely you can google how to handle `InterruptedException` for yourself, yes? I mean, I _could_ do that for you, but I have no wish to deprive you of the experience. It'll be fun! And good for you, too.

Comment: The IBM article "Java theory and practice:
Dealing with InterruptedException", by Brian Goetz, was the third hit in my online search just now. So yeah, the information is out there and easily found. No excuse.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a wait method for this, later you can reuse it, for example:

```
    public static void waitForLoaderToDisappear() {
    _wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(YOURLOADERID)));
}
```

Comment: `_wait` is not compliant with the Java naming conventions.